# sed: N command does not read single line

Tags: sed, newlines

Why sed's `N` command does not read single line?

```
# single line without \n
$ echo -en 'abc' | sed -n 'N;p'
$
# I expected 'abc'

# single line with \n
$ echo -en 'abc\n' | sed -n 'N;p'
$
# I expected 'abc'

# two lines
$ echo -en 'abc\n_' | sed -n 'N;p'
abc
_$ 
# works as expected
```

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Reporting-Bugs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line without a trailing newline is not a line. some `sed` implementations will discard it, some will accept it among which some may add that missing newline back.

In:

```
echo -en 'abc\n' | sed -n 'N;p'
```

sed starts with `abc` in its pattern space. Then proceeds with running the commands specified. The first one `N` is to append the next line to the pattern space. There is no next line, so that causes `sed` to exit as [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and as documented.

Comment: Why doesn't it start with 'abc\n' in its pattern space? Is the `-n` "eating" it? It's strange to me since if I put the above in a file and `cat ...| sed -n 'N;p'` it works.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas Thank you for your answer and link provided. I didn't find such info on `man sed`. It's very useful.

Comment: @sim I used `echo -en' for visually unambigous form. I.e. echo will output string as is visible - without trailing '\n'.

Comment: @loentar - thanks, I still don't understand what's happening as to why. Are you saying that `echo` returns your string minus the trailing `\n` with the `-n` switch? The `-n` switch I though disables `echo` from adding one.

Comment: @sim, no I'd say: `-e` enables expansion of backslash, `-n` disables `\n` produced by echo itself (if you enter `echo ""` it will output single empty line but `echo -n ""` didn't output any char).