# Why the inconsistency with using cat vs. echo piped to this sed command?

Tags: scripting, sed, cat, echo, newlines

Inspired by this question: [sed: N command does not read single line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86989/sed-n-command-does-not-read-single-line) I wanted to understand why there appears to be an inconsistency between the following 2 commands:

#### #1. echo

This command produces no output

```
$ echo -en 'abc\n' | sed -n 'N;p'
$
```

A hex dump of the output from `echo`:

*od - octal dump*

```
$ echo -en 'abc\n' | od -tx1
0000000 61 62 63 0a
0000004
```

*hexdump*

```
$ echo -en 'abc\n' | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 0a                                       |abc.|
00000004
```

#### #2. cat

If I put the string 'abc\n' in a file such as this:

```
1: abc
2:
```

That's a line with the string `abc` on it followed by a linefeed (`\n` aka. `0x0A`). Then pipe it to `sed` as before, I get this:

```
$ cat abc.txt | sed -n 'N;p'
abc

$
```

That's output that includes the string `abc` followed by 2 linefeeds.

*od - octal dump*

```
$ cat abc.txt | od -tx1
0000000 61 62 63 0a 0a
0000005
```

*hexdump*

```
$ cat abc.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 0a 0a                                    |abc..|
00000005
```

I'm a little perplexed as to what's going on?

#### UPDATE

OK so my issue was with how I was creating the file `abc.txt` as [@choroba pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86999/7453). I was creating the file in `vim` and not realizing that it was adding 2 linefeeds. When I enabled visibility of special characters it became a little more obvious:

```
:set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,
:set list
```

Now in `vim` file `abc.txt` looked like this:

```
abc$
$
```

If I created the file as [@choroba suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86999/7453) then the file `abc.txt` showed up as expected:

```
$ cat abc.txt | od -tx1
0000000 61 62 63 0a
0000004
```

And it behaved identical to the original `echo` example:

```
$ cat abc.txt | sed -n 'N;p'
$
```

#### Original issue

My original issue with why `sed -n 'N;p'` wasn't displaying anything was answered thanks to [@enzotib's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87000/7453) answer. The bit from the POSIX standard is what I wasn't picking up on:

> If no next line of input is available, the N command verb shall branch
>   to the end of the script and quit without starting a new cycle or
>   copying the pattern space to standard output

Comment: You might find that `hd` produces easier-to-read hex dumps than `od -x`. Or even `od -tx1`, although personally I prefer to see the characters where possible, as with `hd`. At any rate, both of those will solve the endian issue.

Comment: @rici - thanks I always forget the alternatives, I've used `od` for 15+ years so it's hard to unlearn it 8-). I'll modify my Q to use the `-tx1` switches as you've suggested though so it's easier to read.

Comment: `hd` is also known as hexdump.

Comment: On debian, it's in bsdmaintools, along with `hexdump` (and various other bsd tools like `column` and `cal`). `hd` is the same as `hexdump -C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX standard states:

> [2addr] **N** Append the next line of input, less its terminating
>   <newline>, to the pattern space, using an embedded <newline> to
>   separate the appended material from the original material. Note that
>   the current line number changes. **If no next line of input is
>   available, the N command verb shall branch to the end of the script
>   and quit without starting a new cycle or copying the pattern space to
>   standard output**.

so the behavior is very different if there is or not a next line.

Your input, as you can see from the output of `od -x`, differ just in a newline.

Answer (score 3):

How did you create the file? It contains two newlines, not one. Try again with

```
echo abc > abc.txt
cat abc.txt | sed -n 'N;p'
```

Comment: You'd be correct, I've updated my Q with your feedback. Thanks for setting me straight 8-).